# Can't rename file when uploading through Miles Johnson Uploader

Tags: cakephp

On my files model:

```
var $actsAs = array(
    'Uploader.FileValidation' => array(
        'file' => array(
            'extension'     => array('gif', 'jpg', 'png', 'jpeg'),
            'filesize'      => 5242880,
            'required'      => true
        )
    ),
    'Uploader.Attachment' => array(
        'file' => array(
            'uploadDir'     => 'upload/',   // Where to upload to, relative to app webroot
            'dbColumn'      => 'path',  // The database column name to save the path to
            'maxNameLength' => 30,      // Max file name length
            'overwrite'     => true,    // Overwrite file with same name if it exists
            'name'          => '',  // The name to give the file (should be done right before a save)
            'transforms'    => array()  // What transformations to do on images: scale, resize, etc
        )
    )
);
```

And on the controller:

```
$this->File->Behaviors->Attachment->update('File', 'file', array('name' => 'testing')));
            if ($this->File->save($this->data)) {
```

The file is uploaded fine, and the record is saved on the database. But I wanted to rename the file to avoid people finding the archives by mistake.

Thanks!

Comment: so do you get an error when you try to rename, or you just don't know how to rename the file?

Comment: It doesn't rename. I don't get any errors.

Answer (score 1):

I have run into this same problem. You can accomplish the same task by doing this before you save.

```
$this->data['File']['file']['name'] = 'myNewName';
```